# How to stream real-time audio between Macs

Tags: mac, audio, networking, streaming

What I am wanting to do is create a home radio station that I can have my friends listen to on our speakers throughout the house.  I will use Djay to DJ the station and I was wondering how to stream the audio from Djay on my MacBook (Where I will be DJ'ing) to a Mac Mini (Where the audio will be sent to the speakers from).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way of going at is would be using [SoundFly](http://abyssoft.com/software/soundfly/). It is made exactly to do what you need (stream audio from one mac to another).

The description from the website:

> Soundfly is a very little utility
>   that just sends the audio of one Mac
>   to another, using built-in Mac OS X
>   Tiger technologies, and Soundflower.
>
> It comes as a package containing an
>   application that sends to audio over
>   the network (Soundfly), and another
>   that receives and plays the audio
>   stream (Soundfly receiver). It works
>   out of the box, but if you want
>   further configuration, press ALT when
>   launching either application: you'll
>   be able to configure the Audio Units.

Comment: Thanks, and since I already have soundflower this is perfect!